# Google closure compiler for other languages?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

Are there any equivalent tools to Google Closure Compiler for other languages? For instance, it'd be nice to have one for PHP which would figure out the optimal from my suboptimal code.

Comment: Your asking for a lot here aren't you. JavaScript is one thing but PHP??

Comment: @ChaosPandion: well ... it was the first thing that came to mind. I could have said COBOL but then I wouldn't have had as rapid a response as I have received.

Comment: Just to be clear my comment was a meant to be a small jab at PHP having a reputation as a messy language. Kinda makes me seem lame if no one gets it.

Answer (score 1):

This compiler's result reduces the amount of source code needed to download while still producing the same results. This is less relevant for systems that compile the code, even if just to p-code, and the code is also not sent "over the wire" to the client-side before being executed.

However, as pointed out by @ChadKillingsworth the parsing and semantic checks are clearly features of a compiler that could be benefical to any interpreted language, even if the output is otherwise ignored.

A Google search shows http://www.phpcompiler.org/ is one answer, although it hasn't been updated for almost a year.

Comment: Closure-compiler does a lot more than minify code. The optimizations performed by the compiler reduce execution speed. It also provides compile time type and syntax checking which is extremely valuable. I can see why someone would want such functionality for other interpreted languages.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth Fair enough, yes, the parsing and semantic checks are clearly features of a compiler that could be benefical to any interpreted language, even if the output is otherwise ignored.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth: "... reduce execution speed ...". Funny, I  thought the optimizations improved execution speed.

Comment: Yes - I saw that and wish I could edit that comment. It was decreases excution TIME or increases execution SPEED.